# Auctex: bug in LaTeX-mark-environment?

Tags: emacs, auctex, code-folding

Before I send this on to the developers, I'd like to know if others can confirm this problem. Consider these two environments:

```
\begin{flalign*}
sdfsdf  
\end{flalign*}

\begin{flalign*}
   && A \rightarrow \End_{B}(M) && {; B=\End_{A}(M)}
\end{flalign*}
```

If I set the cursor in the first one and execute `LaTeX-mark-environment` (`C-c .`), then I get the expected result, i.e. marked the `flalign*` environment, including the `\begin/end` lines.

However if I do the same in the other one, it never covers the env. What ever is marked depends on where the cursor is. It is clearly having an issue with the `\End`, presumably because it is ignoring case.

Can others confirm?

(`LaTeX-mark-environment` together with `narrow-to-region` is a really nice feature to have when writing macros).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `LaTeX-find-matching-end` performs case insensitive searches.  To make the search for the `\end` case sensitive, you have to bind the [`case-fold-search`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Searching-and-Case.html) variable to `nil`.  To do that you can [advice](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) the `LaTeX-find-matching-end` function.  This will fix your problem but won't work if there is an `\end` inside the environment (think about a `verbatim` environment).

```lisp
(defadvice LaTeX-find-matching-end
  (around LaTeX-find-matching-end-case-sensitive activate)
  "Perform case-sensitive search."
  (let ((case-fold-search nil))
    ad-do-it))
```

PS development version of AUCTeX has a new function to narrow to an environment (`LaTeX-narrow-to-environment`), so you'll need a single key binding (<kbd>C-x n e</kbd>) instead of <kbd>C-c .</kbd> <kbd>C-x n r</kbd>

---

(daleif addition), one also need to change add to `LaTeX-find-matching-begin`:

```lisp
(defadvice LaTeX-find-matching-begin
  (around LaTeX-find-matching-begin-case-sensitive activate)
  "Perform case-sensitive search."
  (let ((case-fold-search nil))
   ad-do-it))
```

Comment: They already mention thec`verbatim` in `latex.el` but nothing about case insensitivity. And `\End` is a perfectly reasonable mathematical operator

Comment: Now the bug has been fixed directly in the development version of AUCTeX.

Comment: Slightly off topic, will the development version also carry execution hooks for when one changes an env? The is a hook that is executed when a new env is inserted but not when an environment is changed into another. Would be handy when cleaning other people's code

Comment: I've added the corresponding fix for `LaTeX-find-matching-begin` without it `C-u C-c C-e` fails to find the start of the environment

Comment: @daleif Regarding the post environment change hook, I advise you to suggest this improvement to the [`auctex-devel`](https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/auctex-devel) mailing list `;-)`.

Comment: Actually I never manually used `narrow-to-region` before, just used it in macros. I've copied `LaTeX-narrow-to-environment` into my setup, very handy.